# Line number of edit window not showing in interactive window using Visual Studio and conda enviroment

Tags: numbers, ipython, line, conda

I created a python project with Visual Studio, expecting to develop with conda and ipython, so I set the enviroment to Conda, and made sure to check the ipython within it...

I am expecting the following result, which has references to line numbers in the interactive window:

[image: result]

Turns out that i am getting this (without the line number):

[image]

## **What am I missing to achieve the desired result?**

Answer (score 0):

For this walkthrough you should have the Anaconda environment installed, which includes IPython and the necessary libraries:

1. Open Visual Studio, switch to the Python Environments window (View >
   Other Windows > Python Environments), and select an Anaconda
   environment.
2. **Examine the Packages (Conda) tab (which may appear as pip or
   Packages) for that environment to make sure that ipython and
   matplotlib are listed. If not, install them here. (See Python
   Environments windows - Packages tab.)**
3. Select the Overview tab and select Use IPython interactive mode. (In
   Visual Studio 2015, select Configure interactive options to open the
   Options dialog, then set Interactive Mode to IPython, and select
   OK).
4. Select Open interactive window to bring up the Interactive window in
   IPython mode. You may need to reset the window if you have just
   changed the interactive mode; you might also need to press Enter if
   only a >>> prompt appears, so that you get a prompt like In [2].

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-01-create-project?view=vs-2019